# Java Regex non-empty string

Tags: java, regex

I want to assert that name is not empty. I am using the following regex

```
"(?s).*?\"name\":\"\\S\".*?"
```

Works for the following Input:

```
[{"id": 12,"name":"t","gender":"male"}  (returns is not empty)
[{"id": 12,"name":"","gender":"male"}    (returns is empty)
```

Does not work when name has more than one character like the following

```
[{"id": 12,"name":"to","gender":"male"}  (returns is empty)
```

Comment: Why not use JSON parser to extract `name` field and then check length

Comment: This json is part of large string which is not Json.

Comment: Replace `\\S` with `[^\\s\"]+`, and last `.*?` with `.*`. Better, just use `"\"name\":\"[^\\s\"]+\""` with `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `"name":` appears at most once in the string? What is the purpose of `.*?` at the beginning and end if you just want to know if the "value of 'name'" is non-empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\S` matches any *single non-whitespace* char. Note it can also match a `"` char, and that is important to fix if there are no whitespaces between the key-values.

You can replace `\\S` with `[^\\s\"]+` and last `.*?` with `.*` (this latter is for performance reasons):

```java
String regex = "(?s).*?\"name\":\"[^\\s\"]+\".*";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VuiF8l/1/). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - embedded flag option equal to `Pattern.DOTALL`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\"name\":\"` - literal `"name":"` text
- `[^\s"]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `.*` - the rest of the string to the end (as `.` matches any char now, due to `(?s)`).

It is clear you are using with `matches()` that requires an entire string match, `.*?` at the start proves this. However, any dot pattern at the pattern start makes matching slower, especially with longer patterns (yours is not) and with long texts (this is not clear from the probem description).
It makes sense to turn to partial matching by using `Matcher#find()` and a `"name":"[^\s"]+"` pattern:

```java
//String text = "[{\"id\": 12,\"name\":\"to\",\"gender\":\"male\"}"; // => There is a match
String text = "[{\"id\": 12,\"name\":\"\",\"gender\":\"male\"}"; // => There is no match
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"name\":\"[^\\s\"]+\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("There is a match"); 
} else {
    System.out.println("There is no match"); 
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/cYKNBv).